# Extending a variable assignment function to a formula assignment function formally using the recursion principle

Tags: induction, propositional-calculus, recursion

I am reading Derek Goldrei's "Propositional and Predicate Calculus".

Let $P$ be the set of all propositional variables and $S=\{ \neg, \land, \lor, \rightarrow, \leftrightarrow \}$ be the set of connectives. Let $Form (P,S)$ be the set of all propositional formulas that can be constructed from $P$ and $S$. This is what I want to show:

> For each variable assignment function $v: P \to \{ T,F \}$, I want to
> show that there is a unique function $\overline v : Form (P,S) \to \{
>  T,F \}$ such that $\overline v (p)= v(p)$ for each $p\in P$.

On the side note, the author writes that the proof is done by showing that the existence of a function $\overline v$ can be shown by the Recursion principle and I understand the proof of the existence that author provides. He first defines the function $\overline v$ for all formulas having no connectives and then assumes that the function has been defined for all formulas having at most $n$ connectives and naturally defines $\overline v$ for all formulas having all formulas having exactly $n$ connectives in the way that *$\overline v$ respects the connectives*.

Here's the recursion principle that I know:

Let $h: A \to A$ be a function and let $a_0\in A$. Then there is a unique function $f:\omega \to A$ such that $f(0)=a_0$ and $f(n^{+})=h(f(n))$ for each $n\in\omega$.

**How do I see the existence of $\overline v$ as a consequence of the recursion principle as the author says?**
I tried several things but nothing seemed to work. Hints will be appreciated.

Comment: You need a slightly more liberal formulation of Recursion ; see van Dalen, Logic and Structure, page 11

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482486/definition-by-recursion) for details

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks. The existence and uniqueness of the function is a direct consequence of the theorem.

Comment: You are welcome :-)