# Understanding the proof of Definition by Recursion

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, recursion

I’m currently reading *Logic and Structure* by Dirk van Dalen and I am having struggles proving Theorem $2.1.6$ (Definition by Recursion) on page $10$.

**Warning** Before someone flags this question as a duplicate of [Definition by Recursion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/482486), I invite you, at least, to read the end of this post (there I explain briefly why I am posting this). Thank you.

---

### What do we have

Here are some of the definitions and results introduced in the book that might be helpful for the sequel. The chapter on Propositional Logic ($\mathsf{PC}$) starts by introducing the alphabet for ($\mathsf{PC}$)

**Definition $2.1.1$** The language of propositional logic has an alphabet consisting of

$(i)$ *proposition symbols*: $p_0, p_1, p_2, \dots$,

$(ii)$ *connectives*: $\wedge$, $\vee$, $\rightarrow$, $\neg$, $\leftrightarrow$, $\bot$,

$(iii)$ *auxiliary symbols*: $($, $)$.

and the method for obtaining well formed propositional formulas (we will take propositional formulas to be any string of objects of the alphabet from $\mathsf{PC}$)

**Definition $2.1.2$** The set $\mathsf{PROP}$ of propositions is the smallest set $X$ with the properties

$(i)$ $p_i \in X$ ($i \in N$), $\bot \in X$,

$(ii)$ $\varphi, \psi \in X \implies (\varphi \wedge \psi), (\varphi \vee \psi), (\varphi \rightarrow \psi), (\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi) \in X$,

$(iii)$ $\varphi \in X \implies (\neg \varphi) \in X$.

Because we are dealing with inductive definitions, one can easily prove the following induction principle.

**Theorem $2.1.3$ (Induction Principle)** Let $A$ be a property, then $A(\varphi)$ for all $\varphi \in \mathsf{PROP}$ if

$(i)$ $A(p_i)$, for all $i$, and $A(\bot$),

$(ii)$ $A(\varphi), A(\psi) \implies A((\varphi \square \psi))$,

$(iii)$ $A(\varphi) \implies A((\neg \varphi))$.

(*NOTE: in Theorem $2.1.3$ $(ii)$, let $\square \in \{\wedge, \vee, \rightarrow, \leftrightarrow\}$*)

After this, Dalen introduced the notion of formation sequence of a given propositional formula.

**Definition $2.1.4$** A sequence $\varphi_0$, $\varphi_1$, $\dots$, $\varphi_n$ is a *formation sequence* of $\varphi$ if $\varphi_n = \varphi$ and for all $i \leq n$ $\varphi_i$ is atomic or

\begin{align*}
& \varphi_i = (\varphi_j \square \varphi_k) \quad \text{for certain } j, k < i, \quad \text{or} \\
& \varphi_i = (\neg \varphi_j) \quad \text{for certain } j < i.
\end{align*}

Further, Dalen proves that the set $\mathsf{PROP}$ is exactly the set of propositions having formation sequence.

**Theorem $2.1.5$** $\mathsf{PROP}$ is the set of all expressions having formation sequences.

---

### The problem

Later, on page $10$, it is stated the following theorem.

> **Theorem $2.1.6$ (Definition by Recursion)** Let mapping $H_{\square} \colon A^2 \to A$ and $H_{\neg} \colon A \to A$ be given and let $H_{at}$ be a map from the set of atoms into $A$, then there exists exactly one mapping $F \colon PROP \to A$ such that
>
> $$\begin{cases} F(\varphi) = H_{at}(\varphi) \text{ for $\varphi$ atomic} \\ F((\varphi \square \psi)) = H_{\square}(F(\varphi), F(\psi)) \\ F((\neg \varphi)) = H_{\neg}(F(\varphi)) \end{cases}.$$

---

### The suggestion

Exercise $11$ (page $14$ and $15$) helps how to prove this statement. Although, I’m having a really rough time trying to understand it. Hence, any help is more than welcomed.

**$a)$ Give an inductive definition of the function $F$, defined by recursion on $\mathsf{PROP}$ from the functions $H_{at}$, $H_{\square}$, $H_{\neg}$, as a set $F^{\text{$*$}}$ of pairs.**

> I don’t quite know where to start. One think that occurs to me, was to define $F^{\text{$*$}}$ is a similar way as the set $\mathsf{PROP}$ was defined. Hence, I defined $F^{\text{$*$}}$ as the smallest set $Y$ such that
>
> $(i)$ $(p_i, H_{at}(p_i)) \in F^{\text{$*$}} (i \in N), (\bot, H_{at}(\bot)) \in F^{\text{$*$}}$,
>
> $(ii)$ $(\varphi_1, \psi_1), (\varphi_2, \psi_2) \in F^{\text{$*$}} \implies ((\varphi_1 \square \varphi_2), H_{\square}(\psi_1, \psi_2)) \in F^{\text{$*$}}$,
>
> $(iii)$ $(\varphi_1, \psi_1) \in F^{\text{$*$}} \implies ((\neg \varphi_1), H_{\neg}(\psi_1)) \in F^{\text{$*$}}$.

**$b)$ Formulate and prove for $F^{\text{$*$}}$ the induction principle.**

> I honestly don’t know how can I formulate this. I mean, Theorem $2.1.3$ allows us to prove that a certain property is true for all the propositions (elements of $\mathsf{PROP}$). But in this case, we have ordered pairs, and we don’t even know what are the $H$’s maps.

**$c)$ Prove that $F^{\text{$*$}}$ is indeed a function on $\mathsf{PROP}$.**

> After reading this, I realize that maybe the principle that we must formulate and prove will help us proving that $F^{\text{$*$}}$ is a function on $\mathsf{PROP}$.

**$d)$ Prove that it is the unique function on $\mathsf{PROP}$ satisfying the recursion equations.**

> I believe that this is a typical uniqueness proof, but are there any special care that I must take in this point?

---

I tried to search for the Definition by Recursion Theorem from Set Theory (I though that maybe this presented here could be a particular case of a more general one). Although (and I don’t know why) the Recursion Theorems that I found seem not feet in this case.

I also found that this question was already asked here [Definition by Recursion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/482486) and an answer is given there. But I would appreciate if someone could give more details about the argument, because it does not seem clear to me.

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{Prop}{Prop}$You will want to prove that $\forall p \in \Prop \exists! a \in A ((p, a) \in F^*)$.

To do this, you will proceed by induction on $p$.

Edit: you will require the unique readability theorem to make this proof work. It's rather critical. This theorem is actually equivalent to induction on formulas + unique readability, so it's not surprising that you would need both principles to prove the recursion principle.

Base case: $p = p_i$ or $p = \bot$. Hint: consider $G = \{(p', a) \in F^* | p' = p \implies a = H_{at}(p)\}$, and prove that $G$ satisfies properties (i), (ii), and (iii) in your definition of $F^*$ and thus equals $F^*$.

$\neg$-inductive step: $p = \neg q$ and there is a unique $a \in A$ such that $(q, a) \in F^*$. Hint: consider $G = \{(p', a') \in F^* | p' = p \implies a' = H_\neg(a)\}$.

Binary inductive step: exercise.

Once you have this result, you see that $F^*$ is indeed a function $\Prop \to A$. From here, use the definition of $F^*$ to show uniqueness.

Comment: I just have a couple of questions: 1) Is my inductive definition of $F^{\text{$*$}}$ correct? 2) I need to use the Induction Principle to prove that $\forall p \in \mathsf{PROP}\,,\, \exists ! a \in A \, \colon \; (p, a) \in F^{\text{$*$}}$, right? Then, by definition of map, I conclude that $F^{\text{$*$}}$ is the function that I’m looking for? 3) For uniqueness, there will only exists one such function because the $H$‘s are maps, right? Thank you for answer!

Comment: (+1) Some comments : 1) It might be worth mentioning the unique readibility theorem, 2) you have your a’s and p’s mixed up in some places 3) This is the classical top-down approach; one can also construct the function using the bottom-up approach.

Comment: @Lobic Thanks for the constructive comments! I personally prefer the bottom-up approach since it is more predicative, but OP started with the top-down approach. Both approaches work in intuitionist mathematics, but the top-down approach requires impredicative quantification over subsets (and hence either full separation or power-set) while the bottom-up approach only requires the existence of function sets and $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Could someone provide a proof using the so-called bottom-up approach as a separate answer?